# H1 Class Will Not Center

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a headline for a webinar signup page.

Here is what it's doing:
[It's sliding off the left side...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hILgf.png)

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
    <meta name="dcterms.created" content="Sat, 21 Nov 2015 22:11:09 GMT">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text.css" href="style.css">
    <title>Event Lander</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="header-rectangle">
  <h1 class="whiteheadline">Join Us for a Free Webinar!</h1>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
*{
margin:0px;
 }


.whiteheadline {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: -55.656px;
  top: 39.867px;
  width: 682px;
  height: 48px;
  z-index: 4;
  align:center;
  display:inline;
}

.header-rectangle { 
  background-color: rgb(104, 115, 251);
  height: 143px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I've tried adding the inline markup to the html as well as adding different text-aligns multiple times to both css classes.

I want it to fill the width of the browser, no margin, and with the white text in the center of the page with the classes defined.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is the absolute positioning!

Comment: the answer is to use your browser developer tools whie developing. welcome to so. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="header-rectangle">
    <h1 class="whiteheadline">Join Us for a Free Webinar!</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin:0px;
}


.whiteheadline {
    font-size: 48px;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-weight: bold;
}

.header-rectangle { 
    background-color: rgb(104, 115, 251);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 143px;
}
```

---

This center aligns your `whiteheadline` horizontally and vertically

## [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s62jnox7/1/)

Comment: Why not use `padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;` instead of setting a fixed height for the .header-rectangle div?

Comment: @www139 because they are two different things (even if the end results look the same). Padding is for adding padding to elements, not text positioning.

Comment: @Krimson the padding around the text your answer and the question is created with line-height which only offers % values relative to the font size. Padding lets you use percentages which is far more mobile friendly. I guess at this point it comes to personal preference. :)

Comment: @www139 true, the right way however, would be to set the line-height, font-size in `em` units. But whatever works I guess

Comment: Now I realize that this is more oriented toward personal preference. I generally use vw/vh/% values for responsive measurement but ems could serve the same purpose :) -- guess I learned something here too.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if there is anything else I can do. If this doesn't work for you, I will revise it :)

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}
.whiteheadline {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
}
.header-rectangle {
  background-color: rgb(104, 115, 251);
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-rectangle">
  <h1 class="whiteheadline">Join Us for a Free Webinar!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay cool, but you got rid of...
-My blue header height
-My text alignment for the h1 class, which should have been in a particular position on the header.

Comment: What did I miss? Did you want it to be "sticky" or "stuck" at the top when there is an overflow with scroll bars?

Comment: I added the header height but now the text is stuck to the top of the blue header.

Comment: Yes, correct. The header should not stick to the top, it should have info on positioning in my original css

Answer (score 0):

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text.css" href="style.css">`

Use type="text/css" not type="text.css" or delete it all together because it's no longer needed.

The changes are annotated on the CSS. Basically you need to put your `absolute` positioned title inside a `relative` positioned header. That way when you apply left, right, bottom, and/or top positions, it'll be in relation to your header and not the whole page.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/sqL38fh5/)

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font: 400 16px/1.5'Open Sans';
    /* 100% of viewport width and height */
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
}
.whiteheadline {
    font-size: 3em;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    /* 50% of container (i.e. header) then subtract 50% of your title width (580px/2) */
    left: calc(50% - 290px);
    top: 39.867px;
    width: 580px;
    height: 48px;
    z-index: 4;
    /*align:center;<<<Not HTML5*/
    /*display:inline;*/
}
.header-rectangle {
    background-color: rgb(104, 115, 251);
    height: 143px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    /* If using position: absolute, make the container (i.e. header) position: relative */
    position: relative;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <header class="header-rectangle">
         <h1 class="whiteheadline">Join Us for a Free Webinar!</h1>

    </header>
</div>
```